# Is it possible to remove a flag?

Tags: support, questions

In case you flagged a question incorrectly*, would it be possible for you to remove that flag yourself, before a moderator sees it? If not, how could you notify others that it was an incorrect flag?

<sup>*</sup> It could be considered an incorrect flag, if after clarifying, you realize that the post is valid.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible as of now.

Comment: Worst case scenario, ping one of us in chat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

If you're concerned that a Moderator might act on your flag in error, you can always flag again using the "Other" option to explain the error, but I would recommend *against* that.

- Trusted users (> 10k reputation) can see some flags, but not the custom flags, so your explanation won't reach them.
- Moderators can only dismiss *all* flags on a post, not individual flags. So the Moderator won't be able to reject one and accept the other.

If you're worried about a "declined" flag on your Permanent Record™, don't. The occasional "declined" is no big deal. It's when there is a *pattern* of declined flags when there is a problem.

Comment: +1 for "The occasional "declined" is no big deal."

Comment: The situation appears to have changed in the meantime. Close voters as of now can *retract* their vote but cannot vote for that post again. I can confirm that and I suppose you, being proactive on multiple [SE] sites would be knowing it as well. I've not tested this scene for reopen votes. // As for flagging with *Other* reason, I doubt that it is possible anymore or possible only under limited circumstances. I remember doing that and site showed me an error on the lines "You've already flagged this post" or something similar. I can't confirm though. Can you consider an edit in your post?

Comment: @Firelord: I've removed the bit about not being able to retract a vote to close. As for not being able to use the "Other" option if you already have an active flag on a post, I am pretty sure that's a bug.